# Trouble with jQuery delay on mouseenter event

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

This should be simple...  not sure why it's giving me trouble like it is.   I have a simple mouseenter function.  Works fine.   What I would like to do is have the function only launch after hovering for 2.5 seconds.

My working function is this...

### Working script

```
$('.profileimage').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.profileInfo').css({'top': (e.pageY + 25),'left': (e.pageX + 25)}).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Simple enough...  all it does is fade in a `div` element I currently have hidden.

Now, to add the delay, I've wrapped this in a `setTimeout(function()`, because after reading some other posts on here this seems like the correct solution.    So now I've got this...

### Not working script

```
$('.profileimage').mouseenter(function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.profileInfo').css({'top': (e.pageY + 25),'left': (e.pageX + 25)}).fadeIn('slow');
  }, 2500);
});
```

Apparently, I'm not using the setTimeout function correctly, or I assume this would be working.

Working demo:  http://jsbin.com/AqiFEQI/1/edit

Broken demo:   http://jsbin.com/AqiFEQI/2/edit

If you try the working code, you'll see an ugly div pops up when hovering over *Charles*.  In the broken sample, nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will equal to window when the timeout-callback is called. Change to

```
$('.profileimage').mouseenter(function(e) {
    var elem = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
       $(elem).parent().....;
    }, 2500);
});
```

Updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/AqiFEQI/4/edit

Comment: Yup...  that's exactly it.   Thanks.

Comment: Sadly...  it's not the first time I've run in to situations where `this` isn't the object I think it is...  gotta pay more attention to that.

Comment: You're not the only ;)

Comment: Now if I could just figure out why it works so well in my SIMPLIFIED code, but not my production code...  UGH.   Just another day in web development...  /sigh.    Thanks again!